# Sonar plugin postjob measure

Tags: sonarqube

I have a sonar plugin that post a comment in gitlab when there is new sonar issues in a commit. I would like to add difference of code coverage and code duplication in the comment.

This is made by making a sonar plugin based on PostJob.

The issues are recovered by injection of ProjectIssues in the constructor.

Is there a way to recover the Measures in the post job?  I saw that changed in sonar 5.2 but there is no real explanation on how to proceed to read measures.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if the ProjectIssues or PostJobContext have no data you are looking for,  you can use the web API rest: 
WsRequest wsRequest = new GetRequest("api/...");
but beware the last measures will not be computed at the moment of @BatshSide, you have to wait for the Compute Engine to finish his work. 
 So as you cannot wait in 'BatchSide',  look for moving your plugin under @ComputeEngineSide